# react pwa push ui top when soft keyboard opens

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

Problem: when soft keyboard is open, UI shrinks so that everything can fit inside the space remaining. something like this:

```
---------                        ----------                         ---------
                                    flex1                                   ||
  flex1                          ----------                           flex1 ||
                                                                            ||
---------                           flex2                           --------|| 
                                                                            || => (scroll)
                                 ----------                                 ||
  flex2     ==> what happens:       flex3      , what i want ==>      flex2 ||
                                 ----------                         ----------
                                                                            
---------                                                           
                                  keyboard                           keyboard
  flex3

---------                        ----------                         ----------
```

Hope I managed to make myself clear!
my related `index.html`

```html
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#00094B" />
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
```

my `manifest.json` contains nothing related to this matter. only app name and icons.
my `index.css` file

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

so basically I have no idea how to achieve such thing and I have been searching for hours now. any help would be great.

Comment: Can you try setting min-height and overflow to auto for the container and check

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram tnks for the reply. not working. also I think i need to mention that my container has a ```fixed``` position type.

Comment: did you find solution?